# Hive Batch mode List of exit status?

Tags: hadoop, hive

While executing Hive query in batch mode do we have list of possible standard return codes, which can be used proper error logging and monitoring?

Eg: hive -f some_samplescript.hql will returns

```
  0  - Successful execution
  1  - FAILED due Execution Error (like Table AlreadyExistExcetion)
  64 - Syntax Error (like Statement not terminated)
```

If we know list of return codes it will easier for proper monitoring/notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some general rules that were release in hive 10 that were completed under this jira

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3001

These are just general guidance.  Generally the hive error won't give you the actual problem and you will have to go and look in the jobs logs for more details.

Comment: I already had a look at this JIRA, but I was looking if there is any standard codes which can be used in managing the workflow.