# Hadoop Hive Task on SSIS return error code 64

Tags: hadoop, ssis, hive, etl, cloudera

I'm trying to run Hive query using Hadoop Hive Task in SSIS 2015. The query that I tried to run was:

```
create table if not exists table_a
as
select * from (
    select
    code,
    md,
    name,
    region,
    dingestdate,
    max(dingestdate) over (partition by kode_maindealer) as dingestdate_latest
    from dev_stg.stg_ahmsdnssls_xls_master_data_region
) as test1
where dingestdate = dingestdate_latest
```

This query run ok in Hue - Hive Editor and in Hive CLI, but return error in SSIS. The error messages:

```
[Hadoop Hive Task] Information: Hadoop job job_1561011012251_25231 exit value is 64
[Hadoop Hive Task] Error: Hadoop job job_1561011012251_25231 exit value is not 0
Task Hadoop Hive Task failed
```

Have someone experiencing this with SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue by splitting the query into 2 parts:

```
create table if not exists table_a (
code int,
md varchar(150),
name varchar(150),
region varchar(50),
dingestdate timestamp, 
dingestdate_latest timestamp
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' 
stored as parquet 
tblproperties("parquet.compression"="gzip")
;
```

and

```
insert overwrite table table_a
select * from ( 
select 
code, 
md, 
name, 
region, 
dingestdate, 
max(dingestdate) over (partition by code) as dingestdate_latest 
from table1 ) as test1 where dingestdate = dingestdate_latest
;
```

and finally the query runs without error in SSIS.

I'll try the 'Execute Process Task' on SSIS too, to see if it also works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the exit code 64 means that you have a syntax error. It looks like there is version mismatch between the installed Hive instance and the one supported by the Hadoop Hive Task in SSIS.

As a workaround, I suggested running hive scripts using command line (Execute Process Task).

#### Related posts:

- [Does anyone have a List of hive error codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063409/does-anyone-have-a-list-of-hive-error-codes)
- [Hive Batch mode List of exit status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737397/hive-batch-mode-list-of-exit-status)